# Menu items visible based on checkbox

Tags: 7, routes, forms

I want do show/hide menu items based on a checkbox that the user selects when he/she registers.

I use profile2 for register.  Should I use an external jquery script that calls on page load or should I use a hook_menu_alter() in my template file?  I am not too familiar with Drupal code yet and appreciate any input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution 1

Add a custom access callback to your paths, that will then determine whether or not the user should have access to a path.

**Important**: the code below will deny access to those paths. If you just wanted to show a slightly different menu and not block the access to those pages, see solution #2.

For example:

```
function YOUR_MODULE_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['your_path']['access callback'] = 'YOUR_MODULE_menu_access_callback';
}

function YOUR_MODULE_menu_access_callback(){
  global $user;
  if ($user->uid) {
    // Load user's Profile2 profile.
    $profile = profile2_by_uid_load($user->uid, 'NAME_OF_YOUR_PROFILE');
    // Allow access only if the user selected the checkbox.
    if (isset($profile->field_YOUR_FIELD[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']) && $profile->field_YOUR_FIELD[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']) {
      return TRUE;
    }
  }

  // This assumes that anonymous users should not have the access to a
  // particular menu.
  return FALSE;
}
```

This code would go in a custom module.

---

## Solution 2

Add a simple `theme_menu_link()` override in your front-end theme, and skip rendering of those links.

**Important**: this will not prevent the access to those pages, it will just skip rendering of those list items. Also, you must be rendering the links using a menu, e.g. place a menu block somewhere in your theme, and not render the menu directly (e.g. `theme('links__system_main_menu', ...)` or `theme('links__system_secondary_menu), ...)`).

For example:

```
function YOUR_THEME_menu_link($variables) {
  global $user;
  $element = $variables ['element'];
  $sub_menu = '';

  // Exclude certain paths.
  if ($user->uid) {
    // Load user's Profile2 profile.
    $profile = profile2_by_uid_load($user->uid, 'NAME_OF_YOUR_PROFILE');
    // Allow access only if the user selected the checkbox.
    if (!isset($profile->field_YOUR_FIELD[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']) || !$profile->field_YOUR_FIELD[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']) {
      // Define the list of paths that should be excluded.
      $paths_to_exclude = array(
        'sample',
      );
      if (in_array($element['#href'], $paths_to_exclude)) {
        // Stop processing here, meaning this list item will not be included in
        // the menu.
        return;
      }
    }
  }

  if ($element ['#below']) {
    $sub_menu = drupal_render($element ['#below']);
  }
  $output = l($element ['#title'], $element ['#href'], $element ['#localized_options']);
  return '<li' . drupal_attributes($element ['#attributes']) . '>' . $output . $sub_menu . "</li>\n";
}
```

This code would go in the `template.php` file of your front-end theme.

Comment: Awesome answer, thank you very much. Option 1 is exactly what I am looking for.  However, I am struggling a bit.  The menu_alter seems to tackle the link + page. Perfect!  But I have multiple links.  Do I then create an array of my paths or create a new variable?  Also, in the function, the field_MY_FIELD is printing array values. But only the first value gets printed. How do I print all my values?  I tried using an if($profile... == 0){...} but I get an 'unidentified offset: 2' error if not all checkboxes are selected.  Thanks.

Comment: 1/ multiple links - yes, that's why I created an array, so you can list multiple links in that array and use it as is. 2/ not sure I understand completely, would you mind clarifying that a bit and updating the question?

Comment: Thanks for your help!  Had to use _module_implements_alter to get it working. Finally!

Comment: Sure, glad it helped!